# C++ SFML library code not working for drawing a text

Tags: c++, sfml

I am feeling really frustrated with draw() not working in my SFML project. My compiler gives off no errors, my eyes doesn't catch a thing that's off (as a reference I am using official tutorial). The problem is that when window load it doesn't draw a thing. It just stays a white window without any text in it. 
Where could be the problem?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Trying to make a game");
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
{
    //error
}

sf::Text text;
text.setFont(font);
text.setString("Hello, World!");
text.setCharacterSize(50);
text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
text.setPosition(10, 50);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
}

window.clear();
window.draw(text);
window.display();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the window **before** drawing the text...